# Which design pattern is suitable for this case

Tags: design-patterns

I'm writing Java code and here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String type = args[0];
    if (type.equals("TYPE1")) {
        // do something
    } else if (type.equals("TYPE2")) {
        // do something
    }
    ...
    func1(type);
    func2(type);
    func3(type);
}

public static void func1(String type) {
    if (type.equals("TYPE1")) {
        // do something
    } else if (type.equals("TYPE2")) {
        // do something
    }
    ...
}

public static void func2(String type) {
    if (type.equals("TYPE1")) {
        // do something
    } else if (type.equals("TYPE2")) {
        // do something
    }
    ...
}

public static void func3(String type) {
    if (type.equals("TYPE1")) {
        // do something
    } else if (type.equals("TYPE2")) {
        // do something
    }
    ...
}
```

As you see, I have to do `if...else...` in each function, I believe that some design pattern can help me but I don't know which design pattern is the best for this case.

Comment: Can you modify classes of `TYPE1`, etc?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin  OK, in fact it's just a comparaison between Strings.

Comment: Maybe just use polymorphism? Define a common inteface with those methods, implement it the way you need in those classes and just call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in all the functions, you want to do the same thing but differently based on some special criteria e.g. `sorting` an array but with `bubble sort`, `quick sort` or `binary sort` etc dependenign on the type of list you have, then you use [Stratergy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

If you have multiple functions which you want to call from different interfaces or classes based on some criterias then use [Facade Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern#:%7E:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,complex%20underlying%20or%20structural%20code.)

If all these methods are just creating instances of different classes who implement the same interface then it will be [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this pattern is called, but following the principles of OOP, I would **replace conditional logic with polymorphism** and refactor this code somehow like this:

```
class AbstractBase: 
    def func1(self):
        ...

    def func2(self):
        ...


class Type1(AbstractBase):
    def func1(self):
        ...

    def func2(self):
        ...


class Type2(AbstractBase):
    def func1(self):
        ...

    def func2(self):
        ...


class MainClass:
    def factory_method(self, string_type) -> AbstractBase:
        if string_type == 'type 1':
            return Type1()
        elif string_type == 'type 2':
            return Type2()

    def main(self, string_type):
        type_obj = self.factory_method(string_type)
        type_obj.func1()
        type_obj.func2()
```

Comment: This seems like the Factory Pattern